# How to decorate a Python process in order to capture HTTP requests and responses?

Tags: python, http, networking, python-decorators

I'm currently investigating a very large Python codebase with lots of side effects and unexpected behavior, and I'd like to get a grasp on what it's doing by seeing all of the outbound HTTP requests that it makes throughout its execution, at any point in the call stack. Are there any utilities or integration paths that allow me to automatically profile the complete set of network calls made by code written in Python?

Specifically, as opposed to a solely external tool, I would like to be able to interact with the captured HTTP requests and responses programmatically from within the profiled module or an adjacent module; for example to:

- Log the requests/responses using existing [logging handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html) within that codebase
- Publish the request to an event broker like [Kafka](https://docs.confluent.io/clients-confluent-kafka-python/current/overview.html#ak-producer)
- Parse into a [pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#dataframe) for analysis
- Integrate into existing [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) or [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/) suites

I've looked at the offerings of different observability tools. For instance, [Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/configuration/integrations/default-integrations/#stdlib) appears to automatically integrate with Python's `httplib` to create a "breadcrumb" for each request; however Sentry only records this information when an exception is being thrown, and its default behavior is only to publish to its Web UI. [New Relic](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/apm-ui-pages/monitoring/external-services-page-view-web-cloud-network-data/) also offers the ability to view "external service" calls as part of its application performance monitoring offerings, again through its own dashboard. In both cases, however, they each lack an officially-supported Python handler that would permit the tasks described above to occur *within* the process that generates the outbound network requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at [Sentry's Python SDK source code](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/blob/cad2f65316bab4ee5792b1b788c32c57293eea5e/sentry_sdk/integrations/stdlib.py#L57), to see how they integrated with `http.client`, and adapted their approach in a way that generalizes to meet my needs.

Here is the code that I wrote to decorate the `http.client.HTTPConnection` object to tap into requests, request bodies, and response objects. This particular example appends the data I'd like to collect to global lists that live under the profiling module, as well as logging that same data to standard out. You can easily substitute whatever bespoke functionality you'd like in place of those calls to `list.append` and `logger.info`:

```
import logging
import sys
from http.client import HTTPConnection

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="%(name)s %(funcName)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

put_request_content = []
get_response_content = []
request_bodies = []


def decorate_HTTPConnection():
    """Taken loosely from https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/blob/master/sentry_sdk/integrations/stdlib.py"""

    global put_request_content, get_response_content, request_bodies

    real_putrequest = HTTPConnection.putrequest
    real_getresponse = HTTPConnection.getresponse
    real__send_output = HTTPConnection._send_output

    def new_putrequest(self, method, url, skip_host=False, skip_accept_encoding=False):
        logger.info(f'{method}: {url}')
        put_request_content.append((method, url))

        real_putrequest(self, method, url, skip_host=skip_host, skip_accept_encoding=skip_accept_encoding)

    def new_getresponse(self):
        returned_response = real_getresponse(self)

        logger.info(returned_response)
        get_response_content.append(returned_response)

        return returned_response

    def new__send_output(self, message_body=None, encode_chunked=False):
        logger.info(f'Message body: {message_body}')
        request_bodies.append(message_body)

        real__send_output(self, message_body=message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

    HTTPConnection.putrequest = new_putrequest
    HTTPConnection.getresponse = new_getresponse
    HTTPConnection._send_output = new__send_output


decorate_HTTPConnection()
```

Here is a very simple script I used to test its behavior:

```
import logging
import sys
import requests

from http_profiler.connection_decorator import put_request_content, get_response_content, request_bodies

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="%(name)s %(funcName)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)


def test_profile_http_get_via_requests_library(url):
    prev_len_put_request_content = len(put_request_content)
    prev_len_get_repsonse_content = len(get_response_content)
    prev_len_request_bodies = len(request_bodies)

    logger.info(f"Starting the test: GET {url}")
    resp = requests.get(url=url)

    assert resp is not None
    assert len(put_request_content) - prev_len_put_request_content == 1
    assert len(get_response_content) - prev_len_get_repsonse_content == 1
    assert len(request_bodies) - prev_len_request_bodies == 1


def test_profile_http_post_via_requests_library(url, data=None):
    if data is None:
        data = {"message": "Hello world!"}

    prev_len_put_request_content = len(put_request_content)
    prev_len_get_repsonse_content = len(get_response_content)
    prev_len_request_bodies = len(request_bodies)

    logger.info(f"Starting the test: POST {url} with {data}")
    resp = requests.post(url=url, data=data)

    assert resp is not None
    assert len(put_request_content) - prev_len_put_request_content == 1
    assert len(get_response_content) - prev_len_get_repsonse_content == 1
    assert len(request_bodies) - prev_len_request_bodies == 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_profile_http_get_via_requests_library("https://example.com")
    test_profile_http_post_via_requests_library("https://example.com")
    logger.info(f'Requests: {put_request_content}')
    logger.info(f'Request bodies: {request_bodies}')
    logger.info(f'Responses: {[f"{response.status} {response.reason}" for response in get_response_content]}')
```

And here is the output of the testing script:

```
__main__ test_profile_http_get_via_requests_library INFO: Starting the test: GET https://example.com
http_profiler.connection_decorator new_putrequest INFO: GET: /
http_profiler.connection_decorator new__send_output INFO: Message body: None
http_profiler.connection_decorator new_getresponse INFO: <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x7ff40aa5df10>
__main__ test_profile_http_post_via_requests_library INFO: Starting the test: POST https://example.com with {'message': 'Hello world!'}
http_profiler.connection_decorator new_putrequest INFO: POST: /
http_profiler.connection_decorator new__send_output INFO: Message body: b'message=Hello+world%21'
http_profiler.connection_decorator new_getresponse INFO: <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x7ff40aa5deb0>
__main__ <module> INFO: Requests: [('GET', '/'), ('POST', '/')]
__main__ <module> INFO: Request bodies: [None, b'message=Hello+world%21']
__main__ <module> INFO: Responses: ['200 OK', '200 OK']
```